# grid-template-areas: none vs grid-template-areas: dot?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[csstricks says](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#grid-template-areas), we have three property values for `grid-template-areas`, out of which two are `.` and `none`. I can't see any difference in the way `.` and `none` affect the grid. See following:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one none two three"
                         "four five . six" ;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: one;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: two;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: three;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: four;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: five;
}

.item6 {
  grid-area: six;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  
  <div class="item6">6</div>
</div>
```

As you can see above `.` and `none` both leave empty blocks in the grid. I also searched on MDN, but theres no explanation for the difference. So,

**What is the difference between `grid-template-areas: none` and `grid-template-areas: .`?**

Comment: Obviously, erm, `none`. ☺

Comment: none is the *whole* value of the property, not to be used as a named area

Comment: @Paulie_D there would be some reason for w3.org to have both `none` and `.`, otherwise they could've got away with just defining one.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't think so, csstricks gives this example: `grid-template-areas: 
    "<grid-area-name> | . | none | ..."
    "...";`.

Comment: @user31782 css tricks is not wrong but a bit missleading here. You can read `none – no grid areas are defined` <-- note the **s** in areas. The syntax they show is not good to highlight the fact that none is a value on its own. They should correct this

Comment: @TemaniAfif [off-topic] -- seems like it's only you and PaulieD on SO nowadays engaging with flex and grid sort of stuff in css. When I used to participate a few years back, there were more blokes out there :-(

Comment: The strategy of SO (encouraging bad and poor questions) is making a lot of Master away as most of them think it's useless to waste more time as the quality is decreasing. There are still some good people around, less active, but they answer from time to time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-template-areas-property):

> Name:  grid-template-areas
>
> Value: none | `<string>+`
>
> Initial:   none

`none` is a value on its own (`grid-template-areas:none`) and not a value to be used like `grid-template-areas:" none one"`. the latter will fall under the `<string>+` and `"none"` will become a named area and is different from `.`

> - A sequence of name code points, representing a **named cell token** with a name consisting of its code points.
> - A sequence of one or more "." (U+002E FULL STOP), representing a **null cell token**.

Below, I am placing 6 at `"none"` area

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one . two three"
                         "four five none six" ;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: one;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: two;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: three;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: four;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: five;
}

.item6 {
  grid-area: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  
  <div class="item6">6</div>
</div>
```

---

This said, your example will show no difference because you are explicitly placing all your items so "none" and "." will remain empty in all the case. You can put anything there, the result will be the same.

Comment: Seems like I gotta stop reading csstricks. They seem to suggest, `none` can be used in place of one of the _grid-area names_ to disable that particular cell.

Comment: @user31782 we cannot *disable* cells, if you think it's the case, you are missunderstanding something. Even if you use Dot, you will not disable a cell, you will simply create a unnamed cell (with no explicit name to be used width grid-area)

Comment: Regarding you last paragraph _You can put anything there_ -- This way we don't even need `.`, can't we just use any random name, to create an empty cell, that is not used as the definition of grid-area of a grid-item?

Comment: @user31782 `.` is used if you don't want to give a cell a name, that's it. It doesn't mean you cannot put element there or it will be an empty cell.

Comment: I think `.` is just an example string, even using `-` instead of `.` works as well. May be its just a way to ensure that no explicitly defined `grid-area` will fit that cell.

Comment: @user31782 yes it's only about naming. You either give a name to an area or it remains unnamed. In both cases, any element can be placed anywhere.